# I didn't know that he WAS or DID?

Tags: grammar

I hope you have the answer for my question. What is correct:

1) He was joking but I didn't know that he **was**.

2) He was joking but I didn't know that he **did**.

Answer (score 2):

*Was*, to match the verb in the first half of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

As msh210 indicates, one of the words is elided and its presence is implied.  The full sentence would be:

> He was joking but I didn't know that he was joking.

Saying

> He was joking but I didn't know that he did joking.

might be syntactically correct, but what it says that you never knew that this guy knew *how* to joke.